# How to use 'memory:name' output as VectorLayer in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis-3

After running processins in a loop, I try to export results on a single shapefile. 
I've created a vector layer called "regroupee", I merge results with it, and I overwrite "regroupee" with the result.

As Kadir Şahbaz said in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278061/getting-the-output-layer-using-any-processing-run-method) on the option 8, run() method with memory output make a dictionnary, with an instance of a layer (QgsVectorLayer).

The loop works, but when I try to export the final result with QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat, an error say me that "regroupee" is a string...

My code, in the end of the for loop :

```
        alg_params = {
        'CRS': None,
        'LAYERS': [regroupee, calculatrice['OUTPUT']],
        'OUTPUT': 'memory:merge'
        }

        merge = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', alg_params, context=context, is_child_algorithm=True)
        regroupee = merge['OUTPUT']

    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(regroupee, "I:/moulin_z/DONNEES/temp_us235/test_iteration_pyqgis/regroupee.shp", "UTF-8", crs.createFromId(2154), "ESRI Shapefile")
```

And the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 231, in processAlgorithm
TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not 
match any overloaded call:
overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

How can I export the final result as a shapefile ?

Answer (score 1):

The error in this case is because, you don't have a QgsVectorLayer inside the ['OUTPUT'].

First, you have to verify the regrouppe have a QgsVectorLayer in the ['OUTPUT'] with:

```
print(merge['OUTPUT'])
```

Then when you verify that you have QGsVectorLayer, you can try with this line:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(regroupee, "I:/moulin_z/DONNEES/temp_us235/test_iteration_pyqgis/regroupee.shp", "UTF-8", QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2154, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId), "ESRI Shapefile")
```