# Unable to get the geometry of temporary layer created from selected features using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geometry, features

I need a temporary layer with the geometry created from selected features for a processing tool. The temporary layer is created but the geometry is missing. The attribute table is blank.

[image]

But when I printed the geometry it's showing on console.

[image]

Below is the code I am using:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() # layer which has a selection 
feat = layer.selectedFeatures()
fields = layer.fields()

selection = QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'temp', 'memory')
dp = selection.dataProvider()
dp.addAttributes(fields)
feats = selection.selectedFeatures()
for feat in feats:
    geom = feat.geometry()
    wkt = geom.asPoint()
print(wkt)
selection.commitChanges()
selection.updateExtents()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(selection)
temp = QgsVectorLayer("D:\satya\cp.shp", "premises", "ogr")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to select the features in the newly created layer and you use `commitChanges` without `startEditing`. `addAttributes` adds the fields' definition to the target layer. It doesn't add the features' attrribute values.

You can use this script:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # layer which has a selection 
feats = layer.selectedFeatures()
fields = layer.fields()

crs = layer.crs().authid()
selection = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=' + crs, 'temp', 'memory')
dp = selection.dataProvider()
dp.addAttributes(fields)
selection.updateFields()

for feat in feats:
    feature = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    feature.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
    feature.setGeometry(feat.geometry())
    dp.addFeatures([feature])
    dp.updateExtents()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(selection)
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, your code is working well.

Comment: Sure, can you please tell me how to save this 'temp layer' to a shapefile.

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/374102/29431).

Comment: Also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/325170/29431 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/311924/29431

Comment: exec(open('C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp0hckdeoh.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.14\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 4 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 3: argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'

Comment: How to resolve the error??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133084/discussion-between-satya-dalei-and-kadir-sahbaz).