# AttributeError when counting entity number using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, attributeerror, feature-count

I'm trying to count the number of entities but each time I have this error:

> `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'featureCount'

while I have only one selected layer

```py
uri = r"C:\impression_plan\FicheCana.shp"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "", "ogr")


layer_split = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:splitfeaturesbycharacter",
                        {'INPUT': layer, 
                         'FIELD':'NOM_CONCAT',
                         'CHAR':', ',
                         'REGEX': False,
                         'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT"]
        

#dissolve features based on values in an attribute table field
layer_circuit=processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve", 
                        {'INPUT':layer_split, 
                        'FIELD':'NOM_CONCAT', 
                        'OUTPUT':'C:\impression_plan\circuit.shp'})

iter = layer_circuit.featureCount()
print(iter)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

runAndLoadResults is returning a dictionary. And for some reason, it is not returning a layer when you add ['OUTPUT'] at the end like run does:

```
lyr = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/ak_riks_2.shp','FIELD':[],'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
print(type(lyr))
<class 'str'>
```

But you can do:

```
vlayer = processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/ak_riks_2.shp','FIELD':[],'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
cnt = vlayer.featureCount() #(Dont name a variable iter, it is the name of an existing function)
print(cnt)
1
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the following structure:

```
#dissolve features based on values in an attribute table field
layer_circuit = processing.runAndLoadResults(
                  "native:dissolve", 
                  {'INPUT':layer_split, 
                   'FIELD':'NOM_CONCAT', 
                   'OUTPUT':'C:/impression_plan/circuit.shp'})

layer =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("circuit")[0]

print(layer.featureCount())
```

**Explanation:**
Processing tools in PyQGIS return a dictionary that contains an `"OUTPUT"` for key, and a value (`{"OUTPUT": value}`). The type of `value` mainly depends on two facts, (1) the processing tool used and (2) the tool's `"OUTPUT"` parameter (please note that this is not the same as `"OUTPUT"` in the dictionary above). In your case, we are interested in `"OUTPUT"` parameter.

- If you use a file path for `"OUTPUT"` parameter, `value` will be a file path string.

  ```
  result = processing.runAndLoadResults("alg_name", {other parameters,
                                                     "OUTPUT":'c:/foo/bar.shp'})

  # result -> {'OUTPUT': 'c:/foo/bar.shp'}
  # 'c:/foo/bar.shp' is a string and a file path
  ```

  A new layer named `bar` is added to the project and you have to get the layer reference using its name.

  ```
  layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("bar")[0]
  print(layer.featureCount())
  ```
- If you use `"TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"` (or `"memory:"`) for `"OUTPUT"` parameter, `value` will be the ID of new layer.

  ```
  result = processing.runAndLoadResults("alg_name", {other parameters,
                                                     "OUTPUT":'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

  # result -> {'OUTPUT': 'foo_bar_0aefc...'}
  # 'foo_bar_0aefc...' is a string and refers the ID of new layer.
  ```

  In this case, you get the layer reference using `mapLayer` method.

  ```
  layer_id = result["OUTPUT"]
  layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
  print(layer.featureCount())
  ```

For more information, check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280468/29431).