# Making dissolve output as temporary layer using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, dissolve

I want to dissolve my layer by using this script and it is successful, however I want my dissolved layer to be temporary, and my input as any active layer. Can someone help me?

```py
from qgis import processing

inlayer = r'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Documents\Trial PyQGIS\Tobe_Dissolved01.shp'
outlayer = r'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Documents\Trial PyQGIS\dissolve.shp'

processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':inlayer, 'FIELD':[], 'OUTPUT':outlayer})
iface.addVectorLayer(outlayer, '', 'ogr')
```

Comment: Dissolve layer as a temporary layer

Comment: how about iface.addVectorLayer(outlayer,'','ogr') this part? what should i write here?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

In more recent versions of QGIS, do not forget to include the `'SEPARATE_DISJOINT'` argument, see the [Changelog for QGIS 3.26](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-keep-disjoint-features-separate-option-for-dissolve-algorithm) for more details.

So, your code may look like this:

```py
from qgis import processing
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Tobe_Dissolved01')[0]

params = {
    'FIELD' : [],
    'INPUT' : layer,
    'OUTPUT' : 'memory:dissolve',
    'SEPARATE_DISJOINT' : False
}

dissolved = processing.run("native:dissolve", params)['OUTPUT']

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(dissolved)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'` value for `'OUTPUT'` parameter. Use the following lines:

```
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve",
                             {'INPUT':inlayer, 
                              'FIELD':[],
                              'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

If you use `runAndLoadResults`, you won't need to use `iface.addVectorLayer`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: QgisInterface.addVectorLayer(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'

I got an error like this ?

Comment: Ok. I've edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: oh .. Thank you sooo much
it works! , but if it is not soo much trouble I'd like to understand what is the difference between runAndLoadResults and iface.addVectorLayer.?

Comment: how about my input layer ? how can I make it select any layer?

Comment: Can i make the dissolve output layer into a variable again?

Comment: Yes. Please check this: [Getting the output layer reference returned by Processing tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/278061/29431).

Comment: so last time, I run the script successfully , but when i Tried to run it again after closing my qgis , it gave me an error.

from qgis import processing

inlayDir = r'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Documents\Trial PyQGIS\cdc_1stfill.shp'

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:dissolve",
                             {'INPUT': 'inlayDir', 
                              'FIELD':[],
                              'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
                              
                              
#iface.addVectorLayer(output['OUTPUT'], 'Dissolved', 'ogr')

Comment: File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File

Comment: "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 151, in runAndLoadResults
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(alg, parameters=parameters, onFinish=handleAlgorithmResults, feedback=feedback,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 181, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: inlayDir not found